# Metodo para obtener el primer caracter mas repetido de una cadena de texto

Tags: javascript, string, bucle-for

explico mi problema estoy haciendo diversos ejercicios de JavaScript uno de esos es buscar el primer caracter mas repetido de un string utilizando la sentencia **for** en un script, soy recién comenzado en js por el cual logre formular una solución previa a dicho tema luego de eso me encontre con la siguiente prueba que en la cual me quede detenido, dicha prueba requiere ejecutar la misma función pero de una manera mas optimizada en este caso con 1 solo **for** en la cual aún no logro comprender como lograr "compactar" todo en lo mencionado anteriormente.

Mi código utilizado en este caso para el script seria este:

```js
var letra = "MLYXAYMZAXmCYmGXmZY";
var contenedor = [];
var calculo = [];
var micalculo = 0;



letra = letra.toUpperCase()

console.log(letra)



function repetidos(){
  for (var i = 0; i < letra.length; i++) {
    if (contenedor.includes(letra[i]))   {
    }else{
        contenedor.push(letra[i])
        calculo.push(0)
    }

  }

  for (var p = 0; p < letra.length; p++) {

    for (var l = 0; l < contenedor.length; l++) {
          if (letra[p] == contenedor[l])  {
              calculo [l]= calculo [l]+1

          }

    }
  }


  for (var f = 0; f < calculo.length; f++) {

    if ( calculo[f] > calculo[micalculo]) {
            micalculo = f

    }
  }

 }

repetidos()

console.log("La primera letra mas recurrente es: " + contenedor[micalculo])

y este mi codigo de html
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
        
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="codigo.js"> </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ojalas poder resolver este gran dilema que me tiene detenido, saludos y gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una opción es el uso de expresiones regulares:

```js
var str = "MLYXAYMZAXmCYmGXmZY";
function checkDuplicate(str){
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        var re = new RegExp("[^"+ str[i] +"]","g");
        var repetido=str.replace(re, "");
        if(repetido.length >= 2){
            return repetido;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
alert(checkDuplicate(str));
```

Este fragmento te devolverá el caracter repetido, todas las veces que esté repetido, si solo quieres que se muestre una vez, basta con cambiar

```
 return repetido;
```

por

```
 return repetido[0];
```

EDIT:
Para adaptarlo a que se devuelva el carácter que se repite más veces

```js
var str = "MLYXAYMZAXmCYmGXmZYxxx";
var str = str.toUpperCase() ;
var vecesRepetido=0;
var letraRepetida='';
function checkDuplicate(str){
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        var re = new RegExp("[^"+ str[i] +"]","g");
        var repetido=str.replace(re, "");
        
        if(repetido.length >= vecesRepetido){
            vecesRepetido=repetido.length;
            letraRepetida=repetido[0];
        }
    }
    return letraRepetida;
}
alert(checkDuplicate(str));
```

El cambio hace que al encontrarse letras repetidas no se termine la funcion sino que se compare con el que más veces aparecía repetido y si es **MAYOR O IGUAL** almacene hasta que termine el bucle, finalmente se muestra.

Comment: Muchas gracias fran, la verdad no he tocado a fondo el tema de las expresiones regulares pero tengo entendido que resultan bastante útil en esta clase de ejercicios! tengo una sola pequeña duda, me imagino en el caso que si agrego a la variable str la funcion toUpperCase deberia considerar tanto mayusculas y minusculas como repetidas? y  luego si agrego la letra "x" de forma repetida al string tome la letra "x" como valor mas repetido, como podria lograr dicha solución?

Comment: Para aplicar la función toUpperCase basta con hacerlo justo después de la definición de la cadena, es decir

var str = "MLYXAYMZAXmCYmGXmZYxxx";
var str = str.toUpperCase() ;

De esta forma se considerará todo el string como mayúscula.
En cuanto a la segunda parte, si lo que quieres es la letra que más veces está repetida, una forma sencilla es ir jugando con  
if(repetido.length >= 2){
            return repetido;
        }
Por ejemplo puedes hacerte una variable auxiliar que sea el máximo de veces que una letra está repetida y que vaya incrementando y otra para almacenar la letra

Comment: Ok hasta por alli logre hacerlo similar ami código fuente (sobre que tome los caracteres como mayúsculas), pero sigo sin comprender la razón la cual me sigue entregando el valor de "M" y no el de "X", añadiendo el hecho que le agregue mas "x" al string

Comment: Porque si te fijas en  
if(repetido.length >= 2){
           return repetido;
}
Lo que hace es que en el momento en el que encuentra una letra duplicada termina la funcion

Comment: Te he editado la respuesta para que se adapte a lo que me has comentado : )

Comment: Edito mi respuesta, ya que acabo de fijarme en tú ejemplo de mas arriba iba a lo mismo que iba a responderte, Muchas gracias!!